# How to add SOAPAction in SOAPClient header

Tags: php, laravel

I need to consume SOAP web service that require SOAPAction.

this is my SOAPClient instance

```
$wsdlUrl = self::wsdl();
$soapClientOptions = [
    'login'             => self::username(),
    'password'          => self::password(),
    'stream_context'    => self::generateContext(),
    'cache_wsdl'        => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'trace'             =>  1
]
return new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);
```

how to add SOAPAction header?
thanks!

Comment: [The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762501/how-to-call-soap-wsdl-with-header-parameters-in-laravel-5-3) is not Laravel however you will get the idea.

Comment: what is the `$ns` ?@Jamie_D